# How to use the `cc_common.create_link_variables` API?

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm trying to write some complex Starlark rules that link and build multiple dynamic libraries on Linux using the (relatively) new `cc_common` APIs.

There seems to be 2 different ways you can create compile/link actions using this API:

1. Using the `compile()`/`link()` methods, which are relatively "high-level", and
2. Using the `create_compile_variables()`/`create_link_variables()` along with `get_memory_inefficient_command_line()` and then calling `actions.run()` directly with the generated command line.

In particualr, I'm trying to get #2 to work. My question is, how can I create the `param_file` to pass into `create_link_variables`? There doesn't seem to be any Starlark API for this.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/1.1.0/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#create_link_variables

Comment: Why do you need to pass the `param_file` parameter at all?

Comment: Because otherwise there is no way to pass in the list of libs to link.

Comment: So I confirmed last week with members of the Bazel team at Bazelcon that there is indeed a hole in the API here, and that they don't have any intention of working on it :/

Comment: I know how to create param_file and also how to pass the list of libs to the linker without param_file. Let me know if you still care and I may craft out an example.

Comment: @KonstantinErman I'm currently trying to do the same thing and could benefit from your offer of an example.

Answer (score 0):

[agoessling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265637/agoessling) I have shared a couple of source files for you [here](https://github.com/Bazel-snippets/custom_cc_rules)
It should give you a pretty good idea of how this lower level cc_common API can be used end to end.

There are still known holes in this API, i.e. not everything possible with the built-in cc rules also possible through cc_common, but I would say 90% is available.

I am not associated with the Bazel team and the code is the result of my own digging and sniffing. No warranties, but it works for me. Let me know if you get stuck on something - I will try to help.

If you get an idea of how to do some of it better (prettier, more compatible with the built-in rules, more platform-independent, etc.) I am all ears. Good luck!